# Zend Framework 3 - route based on query string

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework3

In Zend Framework 3, is it possible to route to a controller depending on whether a URL contains a query string?

For example, I have these two URLs:

```
/users
/users?name=Bob
```

I would like the first route to call a `UsersController` and second route to call a `NameController`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As rkeet [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606486/3195596), query string is not part of the route. Therefore, we simply added a ternary to the route config array:

```
'users' => [ 
    'type'    => Literal::class,
    'options' => [ 
        'route'    => '/users',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => isset($_GET['name'])
                          ? NameController::class
                          : UsersController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],   
    ],   
    'may_terminate' => true,
],
```

It's self explanatory, but basically the controller that is dispatched is dependent on whether a value is set in the query string.

We decided not to use the `forward()` plugin because we do not want to instantiate an extra controller superfluously.

Comment: Though this would work, it breaks the pattern of a single action on a single route. Something which is explicitly done in ZF. I would seriously advise against this, as it creates some magic, which you know about today, but will be a head-scratcher in a year. Then again, would work ...

Answer (score 4):

Have a read of the [ZF3 docs on Router](https://zendframework.github.io/tutorials/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing/) and possibly [RFC 3986 Chapter 3 - Syntax Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) which shows what is path and what is query.

From [RFC 3986 Chapter 3 - Syntax Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)

> The following are two example URIs and their component parts:
>
> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>       |   _____________________|__
>      / \ /                        \
>      urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

ZF3 route configuration is typically configuration on a path. *(This is also true of pretty much every common framework.)* Yes, variables can be part of a path. As such, they're configured in route configuration. Advanced configuration of framework routing often also allows for changes/requirements in schemes and authorities.

Not part of routing configurations are the 'query' and 'fragment' parts.

If you want to do something, e.g. catch a "name" key/value pair and do routing accordingly, you're going to have to create a "catcher" (or whatever the name for that would be) on the path and determine the redirection yourself.

For example, you could do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674408/1155833). If your controller instance extends the default Zend Framework `AbstractActionController` class, then you should have the [`forward` plugin](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/plugins/#forward-plugin) available. From the docs:

> Forward returns the results of dispatching the requested controller;
> it is up to the developer to determine what, if anything, to do with
> those results. One recommendation is to aggregate them in any return
> value from the invoking controller.
>
> As an example:

```php
 $foo = $this->forward()->dispatch('foo', ['action' => 'process']);
 return [
     'somekey' => $somevalue,
     'foo'     => $foo,
 ];
```

Of course, you could immediately return it.

Another option is the [`redirect` plugin](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/plugins/#redirect-plugin) (same link).

```php
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login-success');
```

With all this you can do something like:

```php
$name = $this->params()->fromQuery('name', null);

if ($name) {
    // dispatch

    if ($dispatchResult) {
        // return special
    }
} 

// redirect
```

Where you redirect to a route name (ie. configured path)

Comment: Thank you for info on the `forward()` and `redirect()` plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Even if rkeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606486/3195596) is technically correct, I'd avoid that solution because it transform a single HTTP request into two (the initial GET and the forward/redirect).

I'd configure the route paths in order to have two different routes:

```php
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'users' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/users',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => UsersController::class,
                    'action' => 'index'
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    'name' => [ // This is the subroute name
                        'type' => Segment::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/:name', // Option 1
                            // 'route' => '/name/:name', // Option 2
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => NameController::class,
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ],
                            'constraints' => [
                                'name' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

With this configuration, you can access the following URL's

```
/users
/users/Bob (option 1)
/users/name/Bob (option 2)
```

Comment: We actually used this route structure initially. However, the `:name` parameter often contains characters that are not suitable for URLs, such as slashes. So, the `:name` parameter must be a query parameter rather than a segment of a route.

Comment: The question was not about route configuration on the "path" part (as shown in my answer), but in the query part (after a `?` in the complete URL). Your answer shows basic route configuration setup as also explained in [the docs](https://zendframework.github.io/tutorials/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing/) I'd already linked.